# Azure Service Bus - *move* message from DLQ to main

Tags: azure, servicebus

I have an Azure Service Bus Queue. Messages that are not processed are moved to the Dead Letter Queue for investigation by a person. I am using Service Bus Explorer to peek at messages in the Queue.

When a message is dead lettered, I want to *move* it from the DLQ to main so that the system can retry message processing. When I select a message in Service Bus Explorer, it *copies* the message into the main queue - the end result is I still have the original message in the dead letter queue.

How do I move messages from the DLQ to Main queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, but I have just found QueueExplorer https://www.cogin.com/mq/index.php which does all the things I need it to do and more (cut/paste of messages from queues is great, as well as the xpath columns for diagnosing issues)

Answer (score 1):

[Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) now let's you remove the DLQ message after successfully moving it to the selected destination queue.

[image: Resubmit]

[image: Resubmit Dialog]

Comment: By which he means this application: https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer

Has an easy 'repair and resubmit' option when viewing a DLQ, allowing you to tamper with the message and select a queue to re-submit to.