# How to move move messages one by one from DLQ to Deffered using c#

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus

I want to move the message from DLQ to Deffered on a particular condition like if a custom property "RetryCount" is greater than 5 else I have to move it to the main queue. Transferring messages from DLQ to the main queue is working fine. But I did not find a proper solution to move messages after reading from DLQ to deffered the queue. I am using the C# code.
Note: I am using the Topic and Subscription model

Comment: What do you mean by "Defer queue"? There's no such thing in ASB as a deferred queue. There are deferred messages.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [QueueExplorer](https://www.cogin.com/mq/index.php) to move the messages from Dead Letter Queues. Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041052/azure-service-bus-move-message-from-dlq-to-main) for more info

Also you can manage it with Service Bus Explorer based on your requirements, you can get the info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?redirectedfrom=MSDN-samples)

Below is a sample code which is used for forwarding the dead letter messages

```
var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
var queues = transport.Queues();
queues.ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo(
        condition: queueName =>
        {
            return queueName != "error" &&
                   queueName != "audit" &&
                   queueName != "centralizeddlq";
        },
        forwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo: "centralizeddlq");
var subscriptions = transport.Subscriptions();
subscriptions.ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo("centralizeddlq");
```